# How can I set HttpResponseMessage.Content in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

As I understand it, it should be possible to set the content of a response message like so:

```
let responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
responseMessage.Content = new StringContent("test")
```

However, when doing so I get the following error:

> **Parser Error**: This expression was expected to have type HttpContent but here has type StringContent

I'm doing this in a tests project in order to stub a response. It's targeting .NET 4.5 and FSharp Core 4.3.1.0

Comment: `=` is equality comparison, `<-` is assignment. See also [Assignment operator in f#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5534368/636019).

Comment: Yep, rookie mistake based on looking at purely C# examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ildjarn said, `=` is equality comparison, `<-` is assignment.

```
let responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
responseMessage.Content <- new StringContent("test")
```